# How can I tell which programs have access to my Dropbox?

Tags: security, dropbox, online-storage

I remember giving some program access to my Dropbox account, but I don't remember which program.

How can I see which programs have read/write power on my account?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Head over to [Accounts/Applications](https://www.dropbox.com/account#applications) page to check out which apps have what kind of access.

[image: Dropbox apps]